# flutter equatable Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found

Tags: flutter, dart, compiler-errors, superclass, equatable

i was following reso coder's [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lPkWX8xFthE&list=PLB6lc7nQ1n4iYGE_khpXRdJkJEp9WOech&index=4) to learn clean structure and tried to make a super constructor as he did and got this `Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.`

here it is

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

class NumberTrivia extends Equatable{
final String text;
final int number;

NumberTrivia({required this.text, required this.number}) : super ([text,number])
}
```

i've tried to do this :

```
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

class NumberTrivia extends Equatable{
final String text;
final int number;

NumberTrivia({required this.text, required this.number});


  @override
  // TODO: implement props
  List<Object?> get props => [text,number];

}
```

it fixed the error but I don't know if it does the same job because I'm a beginner

Answer (score 0):

If you check the `Equatable` constructor, it doesn't take any parameters, therefore the `super` constructor can't have any parameter.

```dart
abstract class Equatable {
  /// {@macro equatable}
  const Equatable();
```

it uses

```
 List<Object?> get props;
```

Comment: I see , but in video that's what he does ..
so is the second code correct ? does it do the same job ? \

Comment: you might be watching old video, it would be better to follow doc, or try to check the video created date , average 6-month-old video mostly outdated.